# Create flask-sqlalchemy database is failing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to import my app config (`db_config.py`) via:

```
>>> from app.db_config import db_session
```

**Error received** `'ImportError: No module named 'app.db_config'; 'app' is not a package`

`app.py` looks like:

```
import pymysql.cursors
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app.db_config import db_session

#app setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    return 'meow'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`db_config.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb',
                                         convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    import app.db_table
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

`db_table.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from app.db_config import Base

Base = declarative_base()

class Tld(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tld'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uri =  Column(String(80), unique=True)
    tmstmp = Column(DateTime())
    auth = Column(Boolean())

    def __init__(self, uri=None):
        self.uri = uri
        self.tmstmp = tmstmp
        self.auth = auth
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm following [this tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/) but Im not receiving the output i expected.

Is something wrong with my `app.py` that makes it not callable like that? or something else wrong with it?

(*First time `alchemy` user*)

Thank you so much

Comment: I take it your package is also named `app`. So you got a naming conflict here. As you module is named `app.py` Python tries to import `db_config` from your module. Try renaming your module (I use `__init__.py`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this myself. I needed to do `from db_config import db_session`, instead of `from app.db_config import db_session`